# jQuery simple pagination links

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination

Is there any script or plugin to JUST change pagination link's page numbers recursively?

Somenthing to start with for example:

```
var max_links = 50;
var visible_links = 10;
var show_next = true;
var show_last = true;
var active_class = '.active';

$('.pagination-links').paginate();

<ul class="pagination-links">
<li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

i mean i only need to generate pagination links bar and animate that nicely

thx in advice

Comment: to be more clear i just need a pagination() method which takes some options and generate pagination links + at link's click change links page numbers recursively

Comment: What's your HTML for whatever it is that you're paginating?

Comment: @Ispuk Are you interested in building it? That's what we do here ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas html should be generated automatically just <ul><li> and <a>

Comment: @JonathanSampson yep! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one out:

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

Comment: it gives me error when tryed ... uhm should be great that thx